# PHP ignores css file

Tags: php, css

Similar thing have been asked already but I couldn't find the right answer.

PHP beginner here experiencing with PHP tabular output. 
I already succeeded in displaying everything in a table layout but no style is applied.

Also the leading a default image on error doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
include_once("condb.php");
 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stock");?>

<table id='display' border="1" style="width:700px"> 
 <?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
 <tr>
<td><a href="<? echo $row['link1']; ?>" ><img src=  <? echo $row['link2']; ?>  onerror="this.src='noimage.jpeg'" height='75px' /></td>      
  <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['descrp']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['vpeu']; ?></td>

  </tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>

<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>

  </body>
</html>
```

mystyle.css:

```
hr {color: sienna;}
p {margin-left: 20px; font-size: 12px;}
body {background-image: url("images/background.gif");}
```

Other suggestions on layout improvement are more than welcome! I have already tried phpgrid (basic)

Answer (score 0):

You already have no style for you Table in your mystyle.css !

Not showing the image may be caused by Addressing ! check your directories and addressing. this may work if you have your mystyle.css in a subfolder

```
url("../images/background.gif");
```

set style for your elements in the page and check the result.

Good Luck